# Compare two HTML documents ignoring multiple and trailing whitespaces

Tags: html, dom

Is there a tool that compares an HTML document like:

```
<p b="1" a="0 "> a     b
c </p>
```

(as a C string: `"<p> a     b\nc </p>"`) **equal** to:

```
<p a="0 " b="1">a b c</p>
```

Note how:

- text multiple whitespaces were converted to a single whitespace
- newlines were converted to whitespaces
- text trailing and heading whitespaces were stripped
- attributes were put on a standard order
- attribute values were unchanged, including trailing whitespaces

**Why I want that**

I am working on the [Markdown Test Suite](https://github.com/karlcow/markdown-testsuite) that aims to measure markdown engine compliance and portability.

We have markdown input, expected HTML output, and want to determine if the generated HTML output is equal to the expected one.

The problem is that Markdown is underspecified, so we cannot compare directly the two HTML strings.

The actual test code is [here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/markdown-testsuite/tree/735a029190bbf94228f1213b22b0fb100ccc0c65), just modify `run-tests.py#dom_normalize` if you want to try out your solution.

**Things I tried**

- [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Orders the attributes, but does not deal well with whitespaces?

  A function `formatter` regex modification might work, but I don't see a way to differentiate between the inside of nodes and attributes.

  A Python only solution like this would be ideal.
- looking for a Javascript function similar to `isEqualNode()` (does not work because ignores `nodeVaue`) + some headless JS engine. Couldn't find one.

If there is nothing better, I'll just have to write my own output formatter front-end to some HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cooking up a custom HTML renderer that normalizes things based on Python's stdlib `HTMLParser`.

You can see it at: https://github.com/karlcow/markdown-testsuite/blob/749ed0b812ffcb8b6cc56f93ff94c6fdfb6bd4a2/run-tests.py#L20

Usage and docstrig tests at: https://github.com/karlcow/markdown-testsuite/blob/749ed0b812ffcb8b6cc56f93ff94c6fdfb6bd4a2/run-tests.py#L74